# Updating a global variable with JavasScript function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, webix

I am attempting to update/reload a datatable based on a combobox selection. My combobox selector works fine and hides/shows the elements I want it to.

However when I am attempting to update the api_url paramater it remains unchanged. It also shows as undefined on my final `console.log()` statement.

```
<body onload="viewChange(1)">
<div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var api_url;
    function viewChange(value){
        if (value == 8){
            $$("devicesToolbar").show();
            $$("accountsToolbar").hide();
            webix.message("Value was changed "+value)
            api_url = "inc/template.php?list=device_list";
        }
        else if (value == 1) {
            console.log(value);
            $$("devicesToolbar").hide();
            $$("accountsToolbar").show();
            webix.message("Value was changed "+value);
            api_url = "inc/template.php?list=all_accounts";
        }
        else {
            webix.message("Value was changed "+value);
        }
    };
console.log(api_url); 
</script>   
</div>
</body>
```

EDIT:

This is my datatable UI code. I need to update that onmy combobox change using that function. Is there a elegant way to do that?

```
webix.ui({
            container:"grid",
          rows:[
              { 
                view:"datatable",
                 select:"row",
                url: api_url,
                scrollY: true,
                scrollX: true,
                        columns:[
                            { id:"project_name", header:"Project Name", css:"rank", adjust:true, sort: "text"},
                            { id:"company_name", header:"Company Name", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"created_date", header:"Date Created", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"weeks_in_cert", header:"Account Age", width:175, sort:"int"},
                            { id:"account_id",  header:"Account ID", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"api_key", header:"API Access Key", adjust:true},
                            { id:"certified",   header:"Certified?", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"certified_date",  header:"Date Certified", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"contact_name",    header:"Contact Name", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"contact_email",   header:"Contact E-Mail", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"contact_phone",   header:"Contact Phone", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"card_processor",  header:"Test Processor", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"client_type", header:"Client Type", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"authorization_date",  header:"Last Transaction", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"api_version", header:"API Version", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"industry_type",   header:"Industry Type", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"terminal_number", header:"Terminal Number", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                            { id:"additional",  header:"Additional Account?", adjust:true, sort:"text"},
                        ],
              }
          ]
        });
```

Comment: when does viewChange get called?

Comment: But your `webix.message()` calls are executed?

Comment: Sorry, viewChange() gets called on body load and also within the onchange event of my combo box.

Comment: The `webix.message()` calls are executed. Also if I `console.log()` within the function the api_url logs the value I've assigned it correctly.

Comment: This works fine. Maybe you think that the `console.log` at the end will log when you execute the function? It only executes when the code loads, and that's why it logs undefined, because you haven't run the  `viewChange` function.

Comment: Your last console.log(api_url) will be executed inmediately and only after the onload and change events will a value be asigned to it. This is why it shows undefined in the console

Comment: Yeah, just run the function, open up your developer tools and type `api_url`, you should see that its value has in fact changed. Or put the console.log at the end of the `if` statements, inside of the `viewChange` function

Comment: I have amended my question to explain what I am trying to do with my UI element. Thank you.